# How to properly remove rvm wrapper?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've created some wrappers using rvm, but i'm not using them anymore, how to properly remove these wrappers?
I created my wrappers using:

```
rvmsudo rvm wrapper 1.9.3@mygemset mywrapper unicorn_rails
```

Comment: Remove the line that create the wrappers. '-' Show us your work, marcos.

Comment: @Grego I edited the question to show how I created the wrappers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is no direct way to remove the wrappers via RVM, but it should be as easy as:

```
rm -i $(which mywrapper_unicorn_rails)
```